# Tabbar view for my flutter app is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-web, visual-web-developer

This is my code. Changing tabbar view contents is not changing the contents.

I've tried changing the children of tabbar view to text but still no effect

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 500,
                color: Colors.teal,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  'Choose Your Topic',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'BalooBhaina2-Regular',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    wordSpacing: 2.0,
                    shadows: [
                      Shadow(
                        blurRadius: 50.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 800,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 4,
                  child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.touch_app)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.movie)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.music_video)),
                      ]),
                    ),
                    body: TabBarView(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.touch_app),
                        Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                        Icon(Icons.movie),
                        Icon(Icons.music_video),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you asked for advice. Please don't bold all the text and the mostly code check is not there so that you add gibberish to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You do not need `Scaffold` and `Appbar` 
Step 2: You can wrap `TabBar` and `TabBarView` with `Container`

code snippet

```
Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    height: 50,
    width: 800,
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
    child: TabBar(controller: _tabController, tabs: [
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.touch_app)),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.movie)),
      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.music_video)),
    ]),
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: Container(
      //height: 50,
      //width: 800,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.touch_app),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 500,
                color: Colors.teal,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  'Choose Your Topic',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'BalooBhaina2-Regular',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    wordSpacing: 2.0,
                    shadows: [
                      Shadow(
                        blurRadius: 50.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 50,
                width: 800,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                child: TabBar(controller: _tabController, tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.touch_app)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.movie)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.music_video)),
                ]),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  //height: 50,
                  //width: 800,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.touch_app),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                      Icon(Icons.movie),
                      Icon(Icons.music_video),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is working fine when using with MaterialApp